# How to use Poloniex API with C# for getting real-time price data

Tags: c#, api

I am using C# code for connecting to Poloniex website, a
cryptocurrency exchange. I have two keys, the first is API key, the last is created by Poloniex and sent me via email. I used the first
key for `PublicKey` and the last for `PrivateKey`. `PublicKey` and
`PrivateKey` on the `ApiKeys.cs` class. When I executed the program, I
got the error

> Additional information: The remote server returned an
>   error: (403) Forbidden".

The link for the [PoloniexApi.Net] project(https://github.com/kripod/PoloniexApi.Net)

```
struct ApiKeys
{
    // WARNING: In order not to expose the changes of this file to git, please
    //          run the following command every time you clone the repository:
    // git update-index --assume-unchanged "PoloniexApi.Net.Demo\ApiKeys.cs"
        internal const string PublicKey = "mypublickey";
    internal const string PrivateKey = "myprivatekey";
}
```

- PublicKey: API key on the Poloniex
- PrivateKey: The key Poloniex sent to email

[image]

Comment: I also swapped two keys together, the same error I got.

Comment: Also show some relevant code, like  how to send the request to the web service, like how to set the url.

Comment: Never share your API private and public key (I edit your question to remove the data)

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to take the exception block. Example:

```
try
 {
   var curr = CurrencyPair.Parse(Scurr);
   var trade = await PoloniexClient.Trading.GetTradesAsync(curr);
   dataGridTradeHistory.Rows.Clear();
   foreach (var trd in trade)
   {
    dataGridTradeHistory.Rows.Add(trd.Time, trd.Type, trd.IdOrder.ToString(), 
    trd.PricePerCoin, trd.AmountBase, trd.AmountQuote);
   }
 } 
catch { }
```